# Merge some array datas depending a range with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 125.00
            [PastDays] => 530
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 123.00
            [PastDays] => 110
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 500.00
            [PastDays] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 500.00
            [PastDays] => 1
        )

)
```

I would merge these datas to have this type on array based on `PAY_Nb_Days`:

- If `PAY_Nb_Days` is between `0` and `30`.
- If `PAY_Nb_Days` is between `31` and `60`.
- If `PAY_Nb_Days` is between `61` and `90`.
- If `PAY_Nb_Days` is between `91` and `120`.
- If `PAY_Nb_Days` is hight than `121`.

So, something like that:

```
Array
(
    ['Between 0 and 30'] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 1000.00
        )

    ['Between 31 and 60'] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 0.00
        )

    ['Between 61 and 90'] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 0.00
        )

    ['Between 91 and 120'] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 123.00
        )

    ['Hight than 121'] => Array
        (
            [Sum] => 125.00
        )

)
```

Could you please let me know from where I can start ?

Here what I tried:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    if($item[PastDays] <= 30) { $sum_0_to_30 += $item['Sum']; } 
    if($item[PastDays] >= 31 && $item[PastDays] <= 60) { $sum_31_to_60 += $item['Sum']; }   
    if($item[PastDays] >= 61 && $item[PastDays] <= 90) { $sum_61_to_90 += $item['Sum']; }   
    if($item[PastDays] >= 91 && $item[PastDays] <= 120) { $sum_91_to_120 += $item['Sum']; } 
    if($item[PastDays] >= 121) { $sum_121 += $item['Sum']; }    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? After you're done you can put all the variables into an array.

Comment: You can use `elseif` and then you don't need to test `>=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [
   'Between 0 and 30'   => ['Sum' => 0],
    'Between 31 and 60'  => ['Sum' => 0],
    'Between 61 and 90'  => ['Sum' => 0],
    'Between 91 and 120' => ['Sum' => 0],
    'Hight than 121'     => ['Sum' => 0],
];





   foreach($items as $item){
         switch($item['PastDays']){
             case ($item['PastDays'] < 31):
                 $arr['Between 0 and 30']['Sum'] += $item['Sum'];
                 break;
             case ($item['PastDays'] < 61):
                 $arr['Between 31 and 60']['Sum'] += $item['Sum'];
                 break;
             case ($item['PastDays'] < 91):
                 $arr['Between 61 and 90']['Sum'] += $item['Sum'];
                 break;
             case ($item['PastDays'] < 121):
                 $arr['Between 91 and 120']['Sum'] += $item['Sum'];
                 break;
             default:
                 $arr['Hight than 121']['Sum'] += $item['Sum'];
                 break;
          }
    }
```

`$arr` will containt information that you need

Comment: Hello, let me check please.